# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError only in one node

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

We have 2 nodes in cluster, 1 nodes works well, the other node sometimes throw 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception, and restart may solve the problem but not always slove, anyone can help?

```
Stack Trace: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxxx/frm/jmswrapper/common/ConnectionFactoryManager
at com.xxxx.yyyy.core.channel.impl.MMDPJMSInboundChannel.service(MMDPJMSInboundChannel.java:55)
at com.xxxx.yyyy.core.thread.task.ServiceTaskRunnableProxy.run(ServiceTaskRunnableProxy.java:11)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

Comment: This is not necessarily a class not found. Look out for the full stack trace, if there is a exception during initialization (constructor or static initializer) of any class that could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Rajeev, the root cause has been found in initialization log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root cause is just what mentioned by Rajeev, we found the exception in initialization log